# How can I get a more useful exception output in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, stack-trace

In Python if I hit an exception, I see a nice useful stack trace like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in c
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in b
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in a
KeyError: 'so cool'
```

In Visual Studio 2010, I get a popup that gives me the equivalent of the last, quite useless on-its-own message. In this particular case, `TargetInvocationException was unhandled`. So I have to click "view detail", a tiny arrow, another tiny arrow on the InnerException "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Finally I have to hover over the StackTrace data part so that I can see the part that makes anything else worthwhile - the line number of where the exception occured.

Is there any way to make Visual Studio show me that information that I really care about, or am I stuck having to drill my way down to the useful information?

Comment: I feel your pain.  We are stuck with the crappy dialog I presume!  Bring back Netbeans, all is forgiven.